# Where do download python PIL module from?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Where do I download the python PIL module from?  I found some sites but not sure if they can be trusted.

This is for my macbookpro.

Is effbot the source?

Comment: Note that effbot.org (since early 2022) is taking a break (i.e. the site is down/offline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

effbot.org is the website of PIL's author and maintainer, Fredrik Lundh, so http://effbot.org/downloads/ can be considered an authoritative source.  There have been a number of forks of earlier versions, and unfortunately, the Python Package Index (normally reliable) [entry for PIL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) is a bit out of date.

Installing PIL on OS X can be problematic because it requires 3rd-party C libraries, like libjpeg, that are not shipped with OS X.  While you can fairly easily install those libraries with the popular open-source package distributors, like MacPorts, Homebrew, or Fink, it is often difficult to get all the options correct to match the Python in use.  For that reason, I recommend using a complete solution, that is 3rd-party libs, PIL, and Python 2.6 all built and installed using the same distribution package manager.  While there may be some first time gotchas, it will usually save a lot of headaches over time.  For instance, using MacPorts, one command will install everything:

```
$ sudo port install py26-pil
```

But check other postings for possible gotchas and variants to use for MacPorts.

Comment: I can't seem to find one that works with my Mac OS and python 2.6

Comment: sudo port install py26-pil will definitely work so long as your macports is set up right.

Comment: MacPorts will work (I use it and recommend it) but there are a few potential gotchas if you are not careful. Possibly the biggest: last time I checked the MacPorts Tk port on 10.6 defaults to an X11 one (ugh!). It has a +quartz variant but that doesn't work on 10.6 64-bit. So you either have to live without Tkinter by selecting the +no_tkinter variant when installing python26 or watch as MacPorts builds all of the X11 client stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Effbot](http://effbot.org/downloads/) is a reputable source. The official source appears to be [PythonWare](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). On a mac, you might want to just use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) or [macports](http://www.macports.org/) to install it.

Comment: Note that the download links on that page are actually links to effbot.org.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OSX there are two solid options. First you must open the Terminal App.

**1. Try installing with *homebrew* with this command:**

- brew install pillow
- brew list (this will check if it installed property)

**2. Or you can install with *pip* with this command:**

- pip install pillow
- pip show pillow (this will check if it installed property)